# Is there a setting to stop Facebook page posts that appear in the news feed showing my own name?

Tags: facebook

When I post as my Facebook page persona, **chronoglimpse**, I don't want my own name to appear at the bottom in the news feed.

I've searched through Facebook's docs but I have had no luck finding an answer. Can adding my name be turned off?

[chronoglimpse Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/chronoglimpse)

[Link to target post, included for those interested only.](http://www.chronoglimpse.com/?id=53599788e4b0ddd860b04422)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Facebook is grabbing this information from the `meta` tags on the shared link:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tested and that was exactly the cause.